# Navigate to a new route but not replace the child route in GoRouter ShellRoute

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I have been trying to navigate to the route (GoRoute), but couldn't find a way to navigate to that route (GoRoute) and then come back to the former route (ShellRoute) while using GoRouter's ShellRoute. I am using a ShellRoute with Bottom Navigation, and when I navigate to a new route in the ShellRoute, it replaces the child in the ShellRoute.

I have this:

```
ShellRoute(
  navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return MarketPlaceScreen(childScreen: child);
  },
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      path: _AppRoutePaths.marketplaceStore,
      name: Routes.marketplaceStore,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        return const NoTransitionPage(child: MarketPlaceStoreScreen());
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: _AppRoutePaths.storeSearch,
          name: Routes.storeSearch,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return SlideTransitionPage(
              direction: Direction.vertical,
              child: StoreSearchScreen(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      path: _AppRoutePaths.marketplacePromo,
      name: Routes.marketplacePromo,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        return const NoTransitionPage(child: MarketPlacePromoScreen());
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      path: _AppRoutePaths.marketplaceOrders,
      name: Routes.marketplaceOrders,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        return const NoTransitionPage(child: MarketPlaceOrdersScreen());
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      path: _AppRoutePaths.profile,
      name: Routes.profile,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        return const NoTransitionPage(child: ProfileSettingsScreen());
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

But that isn't what I want. I want to navigate from the route with `Routes.marketplaceStore` to an entirely new route without replacing the child route. I expected the route with `Routes.storeSearch`, not to replace the child of the ShellRoute, but to exist as a fullscreen page. I don't know if anyone understands. I really appreciate any help you can provide.